# Update based on hierarchy table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a  table of employees- Active or Inactive . The structure is as below

```
create table employee
(
id int,
supervisorid int,
active bit
)
```

Another table Component has items like ..

```
create table component 
(
cid int,
empid int
)
```

Have some sample data loaded [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8013a/1)

How can i update the component table , such that the empid field holds the IMMEDIATE ACTIVE SUPERVISOR ID for Inactive Employees. In the sample case, the result of update should look like

```
Component
---------
Cid  | empid
--------------
 1     1235 
 2     1246
 3     1246
```

I am able to generate hierarchy table for specific employees using the query mentioned in the fiddle page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to make a table for update with first active supervisorID for each non active ID. On the first iteration you select all ACTIVE `ID's` and set their `BaseID` to the same. On each next iteration you select next level of their NON-ACTIVE childs add to the recursive table and save the root `BaseID` in each record. So when you add all records the `BaseID` field for each `ID` is the first ACTIVE parent. Then we leave only `ID's` we need to update (where `Id<>BaseID`) in the `ForUpd` table. Then use this table `Id`->`BaseID` to update the original table.

```
;With OrgChart as        
(        
  SELECT id,id as BaseID
  FROM employee WHERE Active=1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT e.ID, g.BaseID as BaseID         
  FROM employee e 
  JOIN OrgChart g on e.supervisorid=g.id
  WHERE e.Active=0
), ForUpd as
(SELECT ID,BASEID FROM OrgChart WHERE ID<>BAseID)

 UPDATE A SET empid = B.baseID
 FROM component A
 JOIN ForUpd B ON A.empid = B.id
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca121/1)</kbd>

Comment: @mhn I've added some explanation into my answer.